# For What Can I Use Transform.lossyScale in Unity For Example in this Script

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform

Body<>
private float UnitPerPixel;

UnitPerPixel = PrefabsWallTile.transform.lossyScale.x;
float HalfUnitPerPixel = UnitPerPixel / 2f;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html)?

-> it is the absolute scale after all parent object scaling has been applied. In contrary to the [localScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html) which is only the scale in the parents space.

For instance let's say you have a hierarchy with local sales (the ones displayed and configured in the Inspector) like e.g.

```
A (2, 2, 2)
|--B (5, 5, 5)
   |--C (3, 3, 3)
```

then object `C` with a localScale of `3,3,3` will have a lossy scale of `30, 30, 30` which is the result of

```
2 * 5 * 3, 2 * 5 * 3, 2 * 5 * 3
```

Comment: Thank you ,i readed the API but i don't understand , but please can you explain how did you get 30,30,30, and thank you  again :-)

Comment: @mohsensalim Multiply the values from parent to child `2 * 5 * 3 = 30` ;)

Comment: Thank youuuu that help a looot